# Preserve OneDrive sync'd local files during fresh windows install?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, reinstall

Is it possible to backup my local OneDrive files before I do a fresh installation? I want to avoid downloading them all again on the other side of a fresh installation of windows or a new computer.  What are the steps and settings to backup to avoid duplicates and large data transfers over the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this quite often actually. You basically just need to back it up like you would any other folder, and after you setup OneDrive on the new installation, copy everything back in.

> The steps:

1. Make sure OneDrive is fully synced.
2. Stop OneDrive sync.
3. Copy the entire OneDrive folder to backup drive.

   `C:\Users\<username>\OneDrive`
4. Reinstall Windows.
5. Once you are logged in, sign into OneDrive.
6. As soon as the new OneDrive folder is created in your user profile folder, pause the sync.
7. Copy the ***contents*** of the backed up folder into the new OneDrive folder.

> Copy the contents, instead of the root folder, to preserve any permissions and settings on the new OneDrive folder. OneDrive should fix any permissions of the contents automatically.

8. Start OneDrive sync.

OneDrive is going to take a little while to index everything that you just added. Just be patient and finish setting up your new PC.